# How to show the folder path of a document in a Document Set Library View

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, view

I have created a document library which contains an unique content type named Project (based on the Document set content type).
I have created a flat view that only shows documents contained within the different Projects. However, I can not see with this view to which Project each document belongs.
Is there a way to add this information into my flat view ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Please following steps:**

**Step1 Create a Flat view**

- **Library settings** >> scroll page to the "**Views**" section >> click **Create view**
- On the Edit View page, scroll page to the "**Folders**" section >> check "**Show all items without folders**" option>> check "**In folders of content type:**" option

[image]

- **Ok**
- Go back Documents Library and select **Flag** view, you will see the below effect figure:

[image]

**Step2 Create Path filed**

- Open SharePoint Designer 2013
- Go to Documents Library, select **Flat** view, and then click **Edit File in Advanced Mode**

[image]

- Add the following field reference in between the **opening ViewFields and closing ViewFields**

[image]

- Save it
- Now you will notice there is a new column being displayed “**Path**” in the **Flat** view

[image]

Comment: Is this still the only way to display the file path in a library? Unfortunately, the above doesn't work for me because the library contains a quarter million files and an error message appears saying that the number of list items has been exceeded.